# Как удалить лишние символы из номера телефона?

Tags: php

Есть такой номер +7 (977) 801-2041 , нужно удалить все лишнее и оставить только цифры.

Comment: Используйте регулярные выражения для "вырезки" всех символов кроме цифр.

Comment: Получится `79778012041`. PHP вам не нужен.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Удалить всё, кроме цифр:

```
$phone = preg_replace('![^0-9]+!', '', $phone)
```

Можно без регулярных, если знать какие символы нужно удалять:

```
$phone = str_replace(array('+', ' ', '(' , ')', '-'), '', $phone);
```

Answer (score 2):

[**Как то так**](http://ideone.com/TZuBwo):

```
<?php
$tel = "+7 (977) 801-2041";
$tel = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $tel);
echo $tel;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @phone_mobile varchar(100)
set @phone_mobile ='()790231-48869'

select replace (replace (replace (@phone_mobile, 
'(', ''), 
')', ''),
'-', '') as correct_PhoneNumber
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]